# Prevent to open specified url in new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium web-driver and want to test one of chrome extension. I loaded chrome extension by adding the path of chrome extension in my local and it's working fine. But it's giving me also side effect of opening specified url in new tab. If I remove the in code which is responsible for chrome extension then it's working fine[opening specified  not opening in new tab].

I am using following code for that.

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--load-extension=E:\\ExtensionChrome\\Moment\\MomentForYouTube","--start-maximized");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(REMOTEWEBDRIVER_URL), capabilities);
```

The remote url is "127.0.0.1:9515" which is local url and then I am hiting specified url by

```
driver.get("www.google.com");
```

It redirect me in new tab which I really don't want. If I remove

```
options.addArguments("--load-extension=E:\\ExtensionChrome\\Moment\\MomentForYouTube","--start-maximized");
```

this line then it's working fine for me. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with selenium.  It has everything to do with your extension.  We won't be able to help you unless you developed the extension yourself and you post its code here.